# SQL2008R2 Partitioning query

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, sql, table-partitioning

We have a complex query that returns results in 45 secs when run from the 01-05-11 to the 31-05-11, but when it is extended to the 01-06-11 it runs indefinately...  THe tables are partition by month...

I think the indexes are aligned as they where created with the DB...
I am assuming an additional one has been created and is not aligned,

How can I make sure the indexes are aligned with the table partitions

or can anyone think of anything else that could be causing this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you rebuild indexes and statistics on a regular basis? If not I suggest you to schedule a maintenance plan, run it once and the try again. Also have a check on disks performance counters, especially avg disk queue lenght on data and tlog volume of your db server.

Comment: yes, all the normal maintenance, we have just upgraded the server, its 12 cores, 64bit 64GB of ram, but due to all these b****rd functions cant use more than 1 processor and is acting like a cursor as they reference other tables from the functions... needs to be written for sure, im just not the man for the job